# Fetch Images from assets folder and fill gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, assets

I am developing one small application and i have little knowledge in android. so i need your help. Actually i put some bulk of images in assets sub folder. now what i want is, i want to read that all images which i had put into the assets sub folder for example "images" folder and then i want to fill all images in grid view. please friends please help me to fill images in grid view.
I had tried following link but i did not get satisfaction from this site
[Loading Images from assets to GridView with smooth Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515022/loading-images-from-assets-to-gridview-with-smooth-scrolling).

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: i want to get images from assets sub folder and then i want to display it in gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then paste Below code in the CustomAdapter GridViewAdapter

public class  GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<String> griRowItems;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String[] imageUrls;
    ArrayList<String> imagePath;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context,
            int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> mApps) {
        this.context = context;
        this.griRowItems = mApps;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;


        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        this.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_double, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
        }

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        // holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
        // .findViewById(R.id.progress);

        String tempStr = "assets://" +  griRowItems.get(position);
        lazyLoading(imageLoader, tempStr, holder.imageView,
                options);
        return convertView;
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return griRowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return griRowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static void lazyLoading(ImageLoader imageLoader, String tempStr, ImageView imageView,DisplayImageOptions options) {
        imageLoader.displayImage(tempStr, imageView, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,FailReason failReason) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    }
                }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view,int current, int total) {
                    }
                });
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        // ProgressBar progressBar;
        //TextView tvTitle;
        // DisplayImageOptions options;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found this answer on https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

```
public void loadFromAsset() {
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("filename.extension");

    //Load image as drawable
    Drawable draw = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);

    //Once you get the drawable, set the image to imageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(draw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Flower_Mahendi extends Activity {

```
ArrayList<String> listPath;
GridViewAdapter adp;// = new GridViewAdapter(null, 0, listPath);
GridView gridView;
//Bitmap listBitmap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.flower_mahendi);
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    gridView  = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    try {

        String[] files = assetManager.list("kids");
        listPath = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String strImageName : files) {
            String pathAssets = "kids" + File.separator
                    + strImageName;
            listPath.add(pathAssets);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    try {
        if (listPath!= null) {
        adp = new GridViewAdapter(this,R.layout.grid_double, listPath);
        gridView.setAdapter(adp);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```